# ToDo Lists App - Table: jQuery append() / after() /.parent().parent().remove() don't work propery or not recognized

Tags: jquery

I'm following this, making a To-Do list stickynotes http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-sticky-notes-to-do-list-in-css-and-jquery

I need help.
My jquery code does not work / not recognized by browser. What I'm trying to do is to insert a new row when user clicks the 'Add New' button.

I pasted on jsFiddle: ** http://jsfiddle.net/RJjRt/ **

**My jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add button click event
  $("#addNew").click(function(){
    addNewRow();
  });
});

// Add a new row when Add Task button is clicked
function addNewRow(){
 var numRows = $('#taskTable tr').length;
 $('#taskTable').append('
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" id="title-'+numRows+'" placeholder="Your Task Name"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" id="description-'+numRows+'" placeholder="Task Description"/></td>
   <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delete-'+numRows+'" title="Delete Task" value="Delete" /></td>
  </tr>
 ');
}
```

**I also tried**

```
$('#taskTable tr:last').after(...
```

But it didn't work either.

**My HTML code:**

```
<div class="around-table">
<table id="taskTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="title-1" placeholder="Your Task Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="description-1" placeholder="Task Description"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delete-1" title="Delete Task" value="Delete" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="title-2" placeholder="Your Task Name"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="description-2" placeholder="Task Description"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delete-2" title="Delete Task" value="Delete" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="addNew" value="Add Task" />

</div>
```

Thanks you for your help.

---- After fixing ----
Now Adding a new row function works but, deleting row function does not work for the newly added rows...

```
// Function that runs on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add button click event
  $("#addNew").click(function(){
    addNewRow();
  });
  // Delete button click event
  $('.deleteButton').click(function(){
    deleteRow($(this));
  });
});


// Add a new row when Add Task button is clicked
function addNewRow(){
  var numRows = $('#taskTable tr').length;
  $('#taskTable tr:last').after('\
    <tr>\
      <td><input type="text" id="title-'+numRows+'" placeholder="Your Task Name"/></td>\
      <td><input type="text" id="description-'+numRows+'" placeholder="Task Description"/></td>\
      <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delete-'+numRows+'" title="Delete Task" value="Delete" /></td>\
   </tr>\
  ');
}

// Delete the grandparent of the delete button
// which is the entire row of the table (tr > td > a)
function deleteRow(button){
 button.parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiline strings in JavaScript without a little trickery, so your code will fail on the line

```
$('#taskTable').append('
```

and nothing will execute. You can, however, have multiline strings if you escape the newline character with a backslash:

```
$('#taskTable').append(' \
```

Just make sure that the backslash is really the last character on the line.

In this case, though, you could build the html in jQuery instead:

```
$('#taskTable').append(
    $('<tr>').append($('<input>')
        .attr('type','text')
        .attr('id','title-'+numRows)
        .attr('placeholder','Your Task Name')
    ).append($('<input>')
        .attr('type','text')
        .attr('id','description-'+numRows)
        .attr('placeholder','Task Description')
    ).append($('<input>')
        .attr('type','button')
        .attr('id', 'delete-'+numRows)
        .attr('title', 'Delete Task')
        .val('Delete')
        .addClass('deleteButton)
    ))
);
```

Comment: @Yuichi: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the remove problem, and the code you have presently?

Comment: That's because you use the `.on()` method to bind your event. From the API documentation: "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`." Change to `.delegate()` instead, and it will work =)

Comment: Sorry - I misread the docs. You don't want `delegate()` - you want a *delegated event handler*. For details on why, read [the docs on the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: Oh I see, but I just tried delegate() but it didn't work, I simply tried .click() but this also didn't work (only works for the initial 2 rows)...hmm

Comment: @Yuichi: See my previous comment about `delegate()`. I edited your jsFiddle to form a working example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RJjRt/3/)

Answer (score 1):

you try to append multiline string in js it's like this

```
"foo \
bar"
```

or

```
  "foo"+
    "bar"
```

Comment: I will keep it in my brain, thanks a lot! But now removing the row function does not work..hmm

Comment: @Yuichi u should recall $('.deleteButton').click(function(){
    deleteRow($(this));
  }); after added a row, or make onclick attr for a button

Answer (score 1):

Your code throws a SyntaxError: `unterminated string literal`, you should escape the line breaks.

```
function addNewRow() {
    var numRows = $('#taskTable tr').length;
    $('#taskTable').append('<tr>\
           <td><input type="text" id="title-' + numRows + '" placeholder="Your Task Name"/></td>\
           <td><input type="text" id="description-' + numRows + '" placeholder="Task Description"/></td>\
           <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" id="delete-' + numRows + '" title="Delete Task" value="Delete" /></td>\
           </tr>\
   ');
}
```

Comment: Heres a fiddle I made for it: http://jsfiddle.net/4ruhW/ . Figured this answer could use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for asking such a newbie question.